# Dealing with ctype.h integer overflow

Tags: c99, integer-overflow, ctype

What is the proper way to deal with character values which when casted to an unsigned char fall between {INT_MAX + 1 ... UCHAR_MAX} where UCHAR_MAX is greater than INT_MAX.

```
int is_digit(char c) {
    unsigned char uchar = c;
    if(uchar > INT_MAX)
        return MAYBE;
    return isdigit((int)uchar) ? YES : NO;
}
```

Comment: What machine are you on where `UCHAR_MAX` is greater than `INT_MAX`?

Comment: Must I cater all my code towards the machine I am on?

Answer (score 1):

The only way `UCHAR_MAX` will be greater than `INT_MAX` is if you’re on a machine with `sizeof(int) == 1`; *i.e.*, where `char` has as many bits as `int`.  On these machines, `UCHAR_MAX` = `UINT_MAX` ≥ `INT_MAX`.

On a 32-bit (or greater) machine, this is unlikely to be a problem.  So long as the value in the variable `c` comes from a text source, there is no textual encoding I know of that will cause an overflow.  Even ‘UTF-32’ will only have the low 21 bits active.  (Actually, since we’re discussing odd systems, I should say that this works for machines with `sizeof(int)` = 1 and `CHAR_BIT` ≥ 22. ☺)

If on such a machine `is_digit()` was nevertheless passed an argument `c` greater than `INT_MAX`, *it did not come from a text source*.  The undefined behavior is a consequence of putting non-character data into a `char` variable, and that will always be something the programmer did, *not* something the implementation caused.

There is a system where this *can* be a problem: 16-bit `char` and `int`, and the system used a 16-bit character code (*e.g.*, UTF-16) where the high bit can be set.  If such is the case, it behooves the implementation to define plain `char` as signed, exactly for this reason.  With `char` signed, it will promote to (signed) `int` and can safely be passed to the `is*()` family of functions; with `char` unsigned, it will promote to *`unsigned`*`int` and the cast to signed `int` may be undefined.

On such a system, your code is indeed broken, *but that would be your own fault* for the completely unnecessary conversion to `unsigned char` and the dangerous (on this system) cast `(int)uchar`.

To summarize: On systems with `sizeof(int) == 1` it is the implementation’s responsibility to ensure that every code point, when stored in a `char` variable, can safely be passed to the `ctype.h` functions (which expect `int` arguments).  This can *always* be done.  If you’ve stored something in a `char` variable that is not a code point and passed that to `is*()` then the blame for the undefined behavior is yours & yours alone.

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode character set (which is the largest commonly used) has character codes from 0 to 0x10ffff. So, the only possiblity for a character code to be larger than INT_MAX is if `int` is a 16 bit type (or specifically less than 22 bits). If that would be the case, then you simply can not store a character code in an `int`.

If `int` is a 32 bit type (or at least 22 bits) then a character code will not overflow when cast to an `int`.

Comment: You can always use utf-8 and or arrays of char to store single code-points.

Regardless of that fact. String literals are composed of characters and the ctype.h functions do not work on characters. The people that wrote C99 must have thought about this corner case.

Comment: @Elite: Is it a corner case? Do you know of any system that uses full 21 bit Unicode code points (i.e. stores strings in UTF-32) and has a 16 bit int?

Comment: Unicode has nothing to do with anything. Focus on these two facts. You have a character and it has a value (ZOMG! it could even be negative). Functions like isdigit may not accept your value. In closing - the functions in ctype.h are not reliable.

Comment: @Elite: Well, you seem to have your opinion set already, so why ask a question?

Comment: Once again completely irrelevant to absolutely anything. Good job buddy. You know what else? I found the correct answer on another website.